# How to use CDATA in an XML attribute

Tags: xml, cdata

I know how to use CDATA in an XML element. But my question is, can this be used in an XML attribute

Element syntax (which works totally fine)

```
<Test><![CDATA[A & B]]></Test>
```

What i am interested to see is if this can be used in an attribute. Is the below syntax even valid?

```
<Test Sample = "<![CDATA[A & B]]>"/>
```